# Не работает распараллеливание в OpenMP

Tags: c++, многопоточность, распараллеливание, openmp

Я написал простую программу для того, чтобы проверить, работает ли у меня распараллеливание OpenMp.В свойствах проекта я подключил поддержку OpenMp (C++\Язык\Поддежка OpenMp). В коде я указал количество потоков, равное 4. Функция omp_get_max_num() возвращает 4. Но я не понимаю, почему всегда работает только один поток (это видно по количеству выводов).

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include "omp.h" 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int num;
    int max_num;
    int num_ths, th_num;
    #pragma omp parallel private (num_ths, th_num) 
    {
        th_num = omp_get_thread_num();
        num_ths = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("I am ready %d from %d \n", th_num, num_ths);
    }

    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        num = omp_get_num_threads();
        max_num = omp_get_max_threads();
    }
    cout<< "num of threads = " << num << endl;
    cout << "max num of threads = " << max_num << endl;
}
```

На картинке - то , что выводит программа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private (num_ths, th_num)
{
    th_num = omp_get_thread_num();
    num_ths = omp_get_num_threads();
    printf("I am ready %d from %d \n", th_num, num_ths);
}
```

И не забыть ключик компилятора `/openmp`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-directives?view=vs-2017#parallel) информация о директивах OpenMP.